# Checking Equivalence of Types

Tags: python

I snooped around for a while for a way to do what should be a pretty streight forward procedure. I'm receiving a bunch of results from a method, and I want to check the type of each result. When I run `type(result)` on a result I get either `<type 'NoneType'>` or `<class 'sefaria.model.text.Ref'>`.

My first stop was `isinstance()`, but when I did `NoneType`I got an error: `NameError: global name 'NoneType' is not defined` (even though for `isinstance` you're not supposed to use quotes for the type). And when I tried `isinstance` with`Ref`, there were no matches (which I know isn't true, since I checked the results). I tried the full extention and it still didn't work, even when I imported all the relavent packages.

I then tried `type()==type()`, with many variations of sample data or references to these types, none of them working. I then tried `instance is type`, which also didn't work. For good measure, I even tried `base.__class__.__name__` with various equations...

What am I missing?

Comment: show us some relevant code

Comment: `NoneType` is the type of `None`. Just do `xxx is None` for that one.

Comment: You can also get it another way:  `import types; types.NoneType`.  The way @AustinHastings suggested is more usual for this special case, since `None` is a singleton.  Can't comment on `Ref` until you provide a reproducible example.

Comment: `type(None)` is another way to get a reference to `NoneType`

Comment: Actually, @putonspectacles has it: show us your code. Because there aren't very many places where it's a good idea to worry about types. If you're doing it, you're probably asking permission instead of forgiveness, and python is definitely a forgiveness language.

Comment: What you're missing is code in your question. Please [edit] it and add at least one concrete example. See [_How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).